# android-strange behavior of Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using a piece of code to make the user able to share musics of my app via different apps like `Viber`, `Whatsapp`, `Gmail` and... .

```
        Uri theUri = Uri.parse(CopyAssets(
            SHARE));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, theUri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

but it doesn't bring up a full list of those apps. fore example I can't see `Viber` in the list, but `WhatsApp` is in the list. whats wrong with my code?

Comment: possibly viber does not respond to the send audio intent.

Comment: but i can see other apps that make u able to share music via viber

Comment: possibly you want to use `setDataAndType` with both the type and the uri, instead of having the uri in the extra

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You are telling Android I want all apps that support the MIME type "audio/*".

It is up to other apps to tell Android that "I support this type". If they do, they will appear (like WhatsApp does), but if they do not (in the case of Viber) then they will not appear in the list.

Take a look here http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html